# Richtext editor with smarttags

Tags: .net, editor, syntax-highlighting, richtext, smart-tags

I'm looking for a richtextbox control which preferably has support for custom smart tags. The standard rich text editor in .net is a bit limited, so I'm just wondering if someone has a control to recommend.
Some features I'm looking for is 
- being able to represent links with a different text than the link itself
- being able to add a custom set of smart tags, like geo-positions or dates
- mouse hover and custom context menus

Anyone know some editors that support some of this features? :)

Comment: Do you mean smarttags like the one in Word?

Comment: Yes. I want the editor to recognize data labeled as a particular type, for instance a geo position, so the user can be able to click on it for the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is an amazing control/product. It's very extensible so I'd be surprised if it couldn't do what you want.